# How to renew Apple Developer Membership manually?

Tags: apple-id, development, developer-program

How can I renew my Apple Developer Membership account manually? Is it possible to do this?

I know that [developer.apple.com/support/renewal](https://developer.apple.com/support/renewal/) describes renewing but does not explain manual renewal.

Update: Sorry I didn’t wrote the correct English,
I was asking how can I cancel the auto renew.

Answer (score 3):

> You can renew starting 30 days before the expiration date of your existing membership or any time after it expires. Your expiration date is available in your account on the developer website. To renew, sign in to your account with the Apple ID you used to enroll, and click the "Renew Membership” button.

https://developer.apple.com/support/renewal/

Comment: There is no "Renew Membership" button if you have "Auto-Renew Membership" turned on. The question is about how to get the renewal done manually before the expiration date, on which the auto renew will trigger. (Because there's possibly a fear of complications. Why leave it to the last day?)

Comment: The button should appear if one turns off the auto-renew.

Comment: There's no "Renew Membership" button, and toggling auto-renew unfortunately doesn't change it neither. Well..., the typical Apple software "quality"!

Comment: same problem in 2020 :)

Comment: I had the same issue with there being no "Renew Membership" button. I even tried signing in with a different browser. However, once I force refreshed the browser (Shift+Command+R) it appeared.

Answer (score 3):

It's tricky, what worked for me was:

1. Disable auto renew
2. logoff
3. login with a different browser
4. After logging in, a banner at the top offered "Enable Auto Renew" and "Renew Membership"

So, I suggest to try several times, logging off and on and trying different browsers.

Comment: I trying logging out and back in and I still don't see the button :( I'm logged in with the only user on that account.

Comment: I finally found the solution: you first need to add a payment method to your appleid account, and then in the developer account the renew membership button will appear

Comment: Indeed you first need to add a payment method. This can also be a method that doesn't allow to auto-renew it if that's what people may worry about. Then after adding the method, you need to signout and in to the developer portal and the notice will change. Logic however does not end here. When you click to manually renew, you are going to store.apple.com where that chosen method is not available and you can only choose CC.

Answer (score 2):

What happened to me was that I was login in with my admin account and there was no renew button.  But when I called Apple, they said I needed to login with my AGENT account which is the only one that can make the payment.  Agent is more than admin... go figure... But then, after login in with the agent account, the button showed up and I was able to pay.

Answer (score 0):

Cache browser data. Then it worked. After you disable auto renew and cache browser. Then close browser and reopen. When you go to the account a pop up opens at the top of the browser instructing  to update.