# Does apple store my credit card information including name card number

Tags: iphone, itunes, ios-appstore, apple-id, apple-pay

Hello community, 
                i recently bought an apple developer account and paid $99 for it.
This is annual subscription, which will be renewed every year. My question is does apple stored my card information so that it can be used in future subscription or any kind of payment.
Or the payment process during purchase of developer account was one time process.

Main thing is that, if anybody who somehow has access to my apple ID and mobile can use that card for payment or fund transfer which was used during purchase of developer account?

If that card is saved then where can i see it and how can i remove it?

Answer (score 1):

The security of Apple Store servers is closely monitored to prevent any unauthorized disclosure or use of credit card numbers and to protect the confidentiality of your personal information.

> The Apple Store uses the SSL (Secure Socket Layer) industry standard,
>   the highest level of security available today for web-secured
>   applications. SSL relies on a pair of public and private key
>   technologies provided by Verisign, Inc. and based on a 40-bit
>   encryption algorithm developed by RSA Data Security, Inc.
>
> Apple decrypts the data, determines your card’s payment network, and
>   re-encrypts the data with a key that only your payment network (or any
>   providers authorized by your card issuer for provisioning and token
>   services) can unlock.
>
> Apple doesn’t store or have access to the original card numbers of
>   credit, debit, or prepaid cards that you add to Apple Pay also. Your
>   cards are associated with your Apple ID to help you add and manage
>   your cards across your devices.

Source: [More on its security](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203027) with [Card Payment's FAQ](https://www.apple.com/uk/shop/help/payments/card_payment)

You can remove your bank card from iTunes on an iOS device in Settings:

1. Tap **Settings**.
2. Open **iTunes & App Store**.
3. Tap your **Apple ID** (typically your email address at the top of the screen).
4. Tap View **Apple ID**.
5. Tap **Payment Information**.
6. Tap **None** under Payment Type.
7. Tap **Done**.

This will remove your card details from your Apple ID. Note that you won't be able to make purchases, download apps or make in-app purchases until you repeat the process but choose a card type under Payment Type (and enter your card details.)

If you're using an Apple Mac computer, you remove your card details from iTunes using the iTunes app:

1. Open **iTunes**.
2. Sign in with your Apple ID (if you aren't signed in already, then choose Account > Sign In).
3. Choose **Account** > **View My Account**.
4. Enter your Apple ID and Password and press Return.
5. Click **Edit** to the right of Payment Type.
6. Select **None** next to the Payment Method.
7. Click **Done**.

To access the credit card detail for your Apple Developer Program, you can do the following:

1. Log in to your **Apple Developer Account**.
2. Click the **Membership menu**.
3. Scroll down to the **Settings** section.
4. Click on Edit default debit/credit card.

[image]

and you will be directed to the **Apple ID website**.

1. Go to **Payment and Shipping**. and click on **Edit**.
2. Modify your desired credit card information.
3. The Save button will be enabled then click it to save the changes

**Note**: Once you uncheck Autorenew membership option, you can use it for a year and later it will not auto renew if you don't want.

Source: [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201266)

Comment: Can you please show which parts of your answers are quotes from external sources, and add a link for each?

Comment: i dont know how to attach screenshot but its my new apple id and i made a purchase of apple developer program!

Comment: when i follow the following steps :

Tap Settings.
Open iTunes & App Store 

when i click on iTunes&App Store it ask to setup app Store for me, and showing showing "none" in front of Open iTunes& App Store

Comment: @MJGhani: I updated my answer. If the whole answer covers all your question, I would appreciate if you accept my answer.

Comment: @udhy brother i can't find any setting options under membership menu. i wish i could share the screenshots.. it has 1. overview 2. Membership certificates,ids and profiles 4. App store connect 5.cloud-kit dashboard 6.cloud-level support 8. additional resources etc. but it does not contains settings

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/285203/how-to-renew-apple-developer-membership-manually
This answer states 
"you first need to add a payment method to your appleid account, and then in the developer account the renew membership button will appear"
but issue is upon purchasing new account i can't see any renew option.

Comment: https://support.smarteragent.com/hc/en-us/articles/204461285-How-do-I-renew-my-Apple-Developer-Account- will this help ?